# My code isn't working (python, pyautogui)

Tags: python, pyautogui

The code works once even though I have it set in a loop, what do I need to change to make it work.

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
while True: 
    pyautogui.press("e")
    pyautogui.click()
    if w or a or s or d:
        stop()
```

Comment: What are `w`, `a`, `s`, and `d`?  Are you intending to compare them against a variable?

Comment: wasd is the controls for games

Comment: What values do they hold? Are they strings? If so, they'll always be true (assuming they're non-empty), which means that condition will always be true, and `stop` will always be run. What's your intent with that condition?

Comment: E is suppose to be a continuous click and wasd is to stop the program

Comment: Yes. But what do those four variables hold? Can you please show a [mcve], because your code is incomplete right now, so all we can do is guess as to your intent and what your actual code is.

Comment: I'm confused the point of the code is to continuously press e and click and the wasd is to close the program.

Comment: If you want to detect a press of a key such as `w`, you need to actually write that - probably some call to a pyautogui function that deals with keypresses.  Just writing the letter `w` in your code is a reference to a variable that has never been assigned a value, and will therefore generate an error - it has nothing to do with the keyboard.

Comment: And what about the loop not being continuous

Comment: Again, you haven't show what `w`, `a`, `s`, or `d` (or `stop`) are. If any of those are truthy, `stop` will run, and if `stop` causes the loop to exit via some means (an error? Terminating the app?), then the program will stop. You need to give enough info for people to be able to help you.

Comment: wasd are things to stop the program.

Comment: @DylanGuthrie You have to write a program, not an algorithm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from the other replies you gave, you want to press `e` and `click` until it is pressed either `w`, `a`, `s` or `d` and if it is pressed one of those four, you want the program to end. If you want to do that you can use the `keyboard` library in python. The function `keyboard.is_pressed(key)` should check if the pressed key is any of the four above and if it is, it will terminate the program. You can install the library by doing `pip install keyboard` and for example, you can rewrite your program like that:

```py
import pyautogui, time, keyboard
time.sleep(5)
while True:
    keyboard.press_and_release('e')   #this is the same as pyautogui.press("e")
    pyautogui.click()
    if (keyboard.is_pressed('w') or keyboard.is_pressed('a')) or (keyboard.is_pressed('s') or keyboard.is_pressed('d')):
        break   #this is your stop() function
```

EDIT: I've edited the comment with the correct explanation since I've edited only the code earlier.

Comment: I pressed w a s and d and the program didn't stop.

Comment: If you want to enter the letter via input and not hardcode it you have to write:

```letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
```
instead of:

```letter = "e"
```

Comment: No when I press w a s or d the program isn't stopping I want it to press e but I want it to stop when I press w a s or d.

Comment: use `if letter in "wasd":` to simplify the conditional expression.

Comment: @DylanGuthrie Ok so I've edited my response and now it should accomplish what you wanted.